# Android SQLite : How to make query work?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

**This is MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.sqltwo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MainActivity extends Main {
public static final String KEY_NAMES = "";
public static final String KEY_VALUES = "";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Database";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "DBTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper qhelper;
private final Context qcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase qdatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_NAMES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_VALUES + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
public MainActivity(Context c){
    qcontext = c;
}
public MainActivity open() throws SQLException{
    qhelper = new DbHelper(qcontext);
    qdatabase = qhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    qhelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String value) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAMES, name);
            cv.put(KEY_VALUES, value);
            return qdatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
public String getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_NAMES, KEY_VALUES};
    Cursor c = qdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUES);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAMES);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iName) + "\n" + c.getString(iValue) + "\n";
    }
    return result;  
}   
}
```

**This is Main.java**

```
package com.example.sqltwo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button sqlUpdate, sqlView, sqlQuery;
EditText sqlName, sqlValue, sqlQuery_value;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonupdate);
    sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
    sqlValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editvalue);
    sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonview);
    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlQuery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsearch);
    sqlQuery_value = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editquery);
}
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonupdate:
        String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
        String value = sqlValue.getText().toString();
        MainActivity entry = new MainActivity(Main.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name, value);
        entry.close();
        break;
    case R.id.buttonview:
        Intent intentone = new Intent();
        intentone.setClassName("com.example.sqltwo", "com.example.sqltwo.View");
        startActivity(intentone);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

**My Error**

```
02-28 09:23:07.334: E/AndroidRuntime(827): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: TEXT (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE DBTable ( TEXT NOT NULL,  TEXT NOT NULL);
```

What I want this to do?

You can input name and value and update the data into the database.
The view function hasn't been coded yet.
I need to input the data, without the crash.
I need to set up a query system in MainActivity which will work with the switch-case system in Main. 
How do I make it so when I type in query, it takes that data sends it to MainActivity, runs the search and then returns a list of valid values?

-Extra:
How can I make each query returned data set be displayed in a tablerow with rows added when more data is to appear?

-Extra:
Can I have someone realtime live help me? Too much to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an object you do not have a name for the columns yet. You must pass parameters with the name of the columns or initialize the variables as Malaka said.

```
public static final String KEY_NAMES = "column1";
public static final String KEY_VALUES = "column2";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give both your columns (`KEY_NAMES` and `KEY_VALUES`) unique names.

Try:

```
public static final String KEY_NAMES = "column1";
public static final String KEY_VALUES = "column2";
```

You can change `column1` and `column2` to any two different Strings you want, as long as you remember to refer to them by the same name throughout the app.

> How do I make it so when I type in query, it takes that data sends it to MainActivity, runs the search and then returns a list of valid values?

Just run an SQL statement on your database with the inputed values.

> -Extra: How can I make each query returned data set be displayed in a tablerow with rows added when more data is to appear?

Have a UI that displays rows. Do a select statement, iterate over the returned cursor and populate each row. When your database is updated, simply run the select statement again and repopulate the UI. If you add a Primary Key, you can run a subsequent select statement that only looks for data newer than that of the last row's primary key.

> -Extra: Can I have someone realtime live help me? Too much to ask?

Hire someone for exclusive help.